An efficient way for getting and checking user permissions?
I'm building a serverless api for a React app.
This is how I protect the apis with permissions:

The user log in and is given a jwt token
when access any api, the token is send in the Authorization header
api verifies the token, if valid, get user permissions, and compare to the permissions the api required
if ok, process request and return results
if no permission matches, return 401/403

This works, but every time a user sends a request, I have to read permissions from the DB.
Since I'm using Firestore to store user info, this will create many read operations.
Is there more efficient way to achieve this?

Cache the results (in memory) of any database query that you think might be duplicated in the future.
You will have to figure out how much memory to allow for this, and when to expire the cache so that changes in permission are accurately reflected in future calls.  These details are very hard to get right, and you might be better off not caching in the first place.  But without a cache, you can't avoid querying the database for each call (which is not as bad as you think it might be).  There is always a tradeoff in performance vs. accuracy and complexity.

yes you're right. I kind of aware of the trade off, but just needed to hear it from someone else. By the way, just interested, do you know how to cache the results when using cloud run?
